# Navigating html table lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have some html which looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
      <!-- BEGIN NEXT PREV LINKS -->
      <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><font style="color:gray">Previous</font>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="2" nowrap><b>1-100 of 273 employees</b></td>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;<a href="">Next</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" colspan="2"><font style="color:gray">First Page</font></td>
          <td align="right" colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Last Page</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- END NEXT PREV LINKS -->
</td>     
      <td colspan="9" align="right">
      <a href="">Add Checked to Favorites</a>&nbsp;
    <br>
       <a href="">Add Checked to Excluded</a>&nbsp;
    </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
<td rowspan="2"></td><td rowspan="2"></td>        <td rowspan="2" valign="bottom" style="padding-right:5px;"><b><a href=""/></td>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="bottom" style="padding-right:5px;"><b><a href="">Position</a></b></td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="bottom" height="16"><b>Ratings</b><br><img src="/images/shim_333333.gif" width="130" height="1" alt="" hspace="5"></td>        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>        <td rowspan="2" valign="bottom" style="padding-right:5px;"><b><a href="">Birth&nbsp;Date</a></b></td>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="bottom" style="padding-right:5px;"><b><a href="">States</a></b></td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td rowspan="2"></td>    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3" align="right" valign="bottom"><a href="">Clear&nbsp;All</a>&nbsp;</td>      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><b><a href="">In-State<br>Rating</a></b></td>
        <td align="center"><b><a href="">Out of State<br>Rating</a></b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="13" valign="bottom"><img src="/images/shim.gif" width="100%" height="1" alt=""></td>
      </tr>        <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan=13><img src="/images/shim_dddddd.gif" width="100%" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
      </tr>      <tr >
        <td></td><td><b style="">X</b></td>
        <td nowrap><p><a href="">Cruise, Tom</a>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td nowrap>Actor&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center"><img src="/images/stars_2_sm_green.gif" alt="instate&#13;Recommendation&#13;Rating" height="11" width="55" align="middle" hspace="0" vspace="0"></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="/images/stars_4_sm.gif" alt="Summary&#13;Estimate&#13;Rating" height="11" width="55" align="middle" hspace="0" vspace="0"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td nowrap>1948&nbsp;</td>
        <td nowrap>CA</td>
        <td></td><td></td>

              <td>&nbsp;</td> 
      <td align="right"><input type="checkbox" name="employee_cb" value="198720" style="height:15px"></td>
      </tr>        <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan=13><img src="/images/shim_dddddd.gif" width="100%" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
      </tr>      <tr >
        <td><b style="">X</b></td><td></td>
        <td nowrap><p><a href="">Schwarzenegger, Arnold</a>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td nowrap>Governor&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center"><img src="/images/ohuohausd.jpg" alt="instate&#13;Recommendation&#13;Rating" height="11" width="55" align="middle" hspace="0" vspace="0"></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="/images/ohuohausd.jpg" alt="Summary&#13;Estimate&#13;Rating" height="11" width="55" align="middle" hspace="0" vspace="0"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td nowrap>No Current Date&nbsp;</td>
        <td nowrap>-</td>
        <td></td><td></td>

              <td>&nbsp;</td> 
      <td align="right"><input type="checkbox" name="employee_cb" value="61184" style="height:15px"></td>
      </tr>        <tr >
        <td><b style="">X</b></td><td></td>
        <td nowrap><p><a href="">Obama, Barack</a>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td nowrap>President&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center"><img src="/images/ohuohausd.jpg" alt="instate&#13;Recommendation&#13;Rating" height="11" width="55" align="middle" hspace="0" vspace="0"></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="/images/ohuohausd.jpg" alt="Summary&#13;Estimate&#13;Rating" height="11" width="55" align="middle" hspace="0" vspace="0"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td nowrap>No Current Date&nbsp;</td>
        <td nowrap>-</td>
        <td></td><td></td>

              <td>&nbsp;</td> 
      <td align="right"><input type="checkbox" name="employee_cb" value="225747" style="height:15px"></td>
      </tr>  
      <tr height="15">
        <td align="right" colspan="14">
      <!-- BEGIN NEXT PREV LINKS -->
      <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><font style="color:gray">Previous</font>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="2" nowrap><b>1-100 of 273 employees</b></td>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;<a href="">Next</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" colspan="2"><font style="color:gray">First Page</font></td>
          <td align="right" colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Last Page</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- END NEXT PREV LINKS -->

        </td>
      </tr>       <tr>
    <td colspan="12" valign="bottom" nowrap><br>
        <b style="">X</bfdgdfgb style="">X</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br>
    <b style="c">X</b>dfgfdg<b style="">X</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br>    <b style="">F</b>: A dsd "<b style="">F</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;dfgdfg"<b style="">F</b>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br>
    <b style="">E</b>gfhbgdfg"<b style="">E</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </td>
      </tr><tr><td colspan="20">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><img src="/images/shim.gif" width="100%" height="5" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">States:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>CA=California; ND=North&nbsp;Dakota</td>
  </tr>    
 </table>
</td></tr>    
</table></body>
</html>
```

Looking for similar questions, I was able to construct (noting that the table is always 17th in the full html code):

```
data = open("employeetest.htm",'r').read()

root = lh.fromstring(data)

rows = root.xpath("//table")[17].findall("tr")
data = list()
for row in rows:
    data.append([c.text_content() for c in row.getchildren()])
print data
```

This produces a very messy list. My end goal is just to get

```
[['Cruise, Tom', 'Actor', '1948', 'CA'], ['Schwarzenegger, Arnold', 'Governor', 'No Current Date', '-'], ...]
```

However, all this information contained in the table produces a lot of strange elements. I know I can clean the resultant `\xa0` by replacing with a single space. I'm not really sure how to navigate this further. Thanks!

Comment: The data is not in any table, also what does `...` represent in your expected output?

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but isn't it encased in a `<table> </table` and then there are `<tr> </tr>` and `<td> </td>` for the elements. `...` was meant to represent a continuation of the same pattern.

Comment: Yep, I missed the opening tag. So all you want from what is posted is the three sublists in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the `...` should be in your expected output but to get the data in the first three sublists, you can narrow down the search looking for trs that have a nowrap attribute and only one attribute altogether:

```
from lxml import html

root = html.fromstring(h)
rows = root.xpath("//tr[td[@nowrap and text() and count(@*)=1]]")
data = list()

for row in rows:
    print(row.xpath(".//td[@nowrap]//text()"))
```

Output:

```
['Cruise, Tom', u'\xa0', u'Actor\xa0', u'1948\xa0', 'CA']
['Schwarzenegger, Arnold', u'\xa0', u'Governor\xa0', u'No Current Date\xa0', '-']
['Obama, Barack', u'\xa0', u'President\xa0', u'No Current Date\xa0', '-']
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked quite well. I just had to change the encoding (for my purposes), in case someone else stumbles across this and needs that information.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to traverse the html document and get a more refined XPath. Additionally, you face the challenge of related data in different elements requiring two XPath expressions. This will require some manipulation to get the final related results together:

```
import lxml.etree as et

with open("employeetest.htm",'r') as f:
    text = f.read().replace('&nbsp', '').replace(';', '')
root = et.HTML(text)

# XPATH LISTS (W/ RELATED ITEMS)
items1 = root.xpath("//td/p/a/text()")
items2 = root.xpath("//td[p/a/text()]/following-sibling::td/text()")

# NUMBER OF ITEMS RELATED BETWEEN EACH
r = int(len(items2)/len(items1))

# ITERATE THROUGH WITH LIST SLICE AND APPEND 
data = []

for i in range(r):
    inner = []
    inner.append(items1[i])
    for j in items2[0+i*r:2+i*r]:    # SLICE BY EVERY THREE ITEMS
        inner.append(j)

    data.append(inner)

print(data)
# [['Cruise, Tom', 'Actor', '1948'], 
#  ['Schwarzenegger, Arnold', 'Governor', 'No Current Date'], 
#  ['Obama, Barack', 'President', 'No Current Date']]
```